# What's the name of the process of making wood smooth?

Tags: word-request, verbs

Example sentence:

> Sandpaper is used to __ wood.

I thought of *polishing* but I think that's the process of making wood shiny (e.g. using wax or varnish).

What's the correct word to use here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directly related verb is **to sand**. It means to use sandpaper (which as you know comes in different degrees of coarseness or grit) to smooth the surface, either by hand, manually, or with a hand-sander that spins or oscillates, or with a belt-sander that uses a loop of sandpaper.

Comment: For wood, _to sand_ is the right word. _To smooth (out)_ would also be OK, but not as specific. For other surfaces, _to polish, to grind,_ or in extreme cases like telescope mirrors, _to figure_ (which means **extreme** smoothness and shape), would also work.